# Mental Math Techniques

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic, big-list, mental-arithmetic

What are some interesting mental math techniques that you know?

Here's one that I got from my Grandmother who got it from a book: To square a two-digit number (from $26$ to $49$), take the number minus $25$ and put that in the first two digits, and then add the square of $50$ minus the number: $$(\text{number}-25)\times100+(50-\text{number})^2$$ For example, to do $47^2$ we have $47-25=22$ for the first two digits and $(50-47)^2=9$ for the last two so we get $47^2=2209$.

Bonus points if you include justification! For this trick, $$100(n-25)+(50-n)^2=100n-2500+2500-100n+n^2=n^2$$

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: this question is opinion based, which is against the guidelines of the math stack exchange.

Comment: @mathguy There's nothing opinionated about a mental math trick. It either works or it doesn't. How could this possibly result in arguments?

Comment: You are asking for the *best* mental tricks -- that sounds opinion based to me...

Comment: @Thomas I meant the best mental tricks known to the person answering. I'll edit the question phrasing.

Comment: There it's not opinion based anymore. Please don't close.

Comment: For those of you who downvoted, do you still consider the question opinion based? Is there anything I could do to make it better?

Comment: If you look at the "Related" questions listed on this page, you'll see that there have been many questions on mental math on this site already. It might be worth having a look at a few of them, to see that we are not creating duplications --- indeed, it is possible that the current question should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, we have the classic trick $$9\times n=(10\times n)-n$$ which works because of distributivity. This can be generalized as follows: $$99n=100n-n$$ so for example $$99\cdot 54=5400-54=5346$$ It also helps simplify generic calculations. E.g., $$17\cdot 8=17\cdot 10-17\cdot 2=170-34=136$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Makes multiplication of multi-digit numbers easier. The above is the following problem:

```
   14759
x 365421
```

This is how they teach multiplication in Japan. You may be thinking, you draw this in your mind? No, there's a shortcut for this method.

Take for instance:

```
  21
x 32
```

You can [draw it](http://www.noisecoveredindirt.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/math2.jpg) to get the answer. But the drawing is basically giving you a simpler way of solving it. This is how you solve it:

http://sketchtoy.com/60373071

Here's a little tougher one that I did mentally:

http://sketchtoy.com/60373153

Makes mental multiplication of multi-digit numbers easier.

Comment: You can visualize a $5\times 6$ array of numbers in your head?!

Comment: @user7530 Obviously not this big but for 3/4-digit numbers it's useful.

Comment: So... the standard multiplication algorithm, but less efficient.  Looks pretty, though, and probably useful as an educational tool more than anything.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If I did 721 x 341 the standard way it's much more painful than this: http://sketchtoy.com/60373153

Comment: I mean, what you're doing is adding every term in the expansion of the product $(7\cdot 10^2 + 2\cdot 10 + 1)(3 \cdot 10^2 + 4 \cdot 10 + 1)$.  The quickness in your usage comes from the fact that you're able to group together the terms of a common power of $10$, and that this happens to work well for you.  I'm not sure most would agree that the computation you do is easier than the usual order of adding the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick to multiply two numbers between 10 and 19 together, say $10 + x$ and $10 + y$: Compute $10 + x + y$, put a zero at the end (multiply by 10), and add $x\cdot y$. Thus $(10+x)(10+y) = 10\cdot(10 + x + y) + xy$.

Easy with algebra. I learned this from my mother who had only an 8th grade education and no algebra.